# Probability Problem - Find combinations

Tags: probability

**In a box there’s 12 light-bulbs, where 4 are 25 W, 3 are 40 W and 5 are 60 W. You are picking 5 light-bulbs from the box randomly without replacement.
What’s the probability that:
At most, 1 light-bulb is 25 W.**

*Solution:*
[image]

What’s the best method to solve these kinds of problems? In my attempted solution above, I started to write down some possible combinations that fulfill the condition “**At most, 1 light-bulb is 25 W**”.

I am thinking that:
After I know all possible combinations, I should calculate every probability for each combination and then add all probabilities together. Then divide with:
[image]

What’s the best way to do this? My method means trying to figure them out “one by one”. But I think that method would be destined to fail somewhere along the way.

Comment: Make a distinction between 25 W bulbs and non-25 W bulbs only (two groups).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You needn't calculate "every probability for each combination"

Just adding those for zero and one $25$W bulbs with other categories lumped together will do for counting favorable ways

$Pr = \dfrac{\dbinom40 \dbinom85 + \dbinom41\dbinom84}{\dbinom{12}{5}}$